# Unable to get rid of Diamond issue in C++

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

```
Please have a look at the code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 class base1
 {
 public:
    int x,y;
 };
  class base2
 {
 public:
    int x, z;
 };

 class derived: virtual public  base1,virtual public  base2
 {
    public:
     void display(int a, int b, int c)
     {
        x=a;
        y=b;
        z=c;
        cout<<x<<endl<<y<<endl<<z<,endl;

     }
 };

 int main()
 {
    derived dr;
    dr.display(1,2,3);
 }
```

As the base classes base1 and base2 are made virtual, it should solve the issue of declaration of x in these classes. But, it is not. It is giving me an error:
error: reference to ‘x’ is ambiguous
Can anyone please put light?

Comment: A) You have no diamond. B) how is the compiler supposed to know which `x` you want?  Do you know which `x` you want to modify?

Comment: Virtual inheritance does not "merge" members, it "merges" base class subobjects.

Comment: yes, this is not a diamond problem. agreed. I want to modify the x from base class 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a diamond inheritance issue. You have:

```
base1  base2
 ^      ^
 |      |
 \      /
  \    /
   \  /
    \/
 derived
```

The problem is that both `base1` and `base2` have member `x`.

You need to disambiguate `x` from `derived` using `base1::` or `base2::` even though you don't have a diamond inheritance.

Ignoring for the time being the rationale for changing the values of member variables in `derived::display`, you can use:

```
class derived: virtual public  base1,virtual public  base2
{
   public:
      void display(int a, int b, int c)
      {
         base1::x=a;
         y=b;
         z=c;
         cout<<base1::x<<endl<<y<<endl<<z<<endl;
      }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of referencing to vague `x`, `y`, and `z` variables, use `base1.x` or `base2.x`. For example:

CHANGE

```
    x=a;
    y=b;
    z=c;
    cout<<x<<endl<<y<<endl<<z<<endl;
```

TO

```
    base1 b1;
    base2 b2;
    b1.x=a;
    b2.x=a;
    b1.y=b;
    b2.z=c;
    cout<<b2.x<<endl<<b1.y<<endl<<b2.z<,endl;
```

OR TO: (if you wanted to change the `this` values)

```
    base1::x=a;
    base2::x=a;
    base1::y=b;
    base2::z=c;
    cout<<base2::x<<endl<<base1::y<<endl<<base2::z<,endl;
```

Comment: OP presumably wants to change members of `this`, not members of local objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all who commented!